# How do I clear a ScatterPlotItem in PYQTGRAPH

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqtgraph

I am attempting to move a "cursor" around my graph using ScatterPlotItem and a '+' symbol as the cursor. The cursor updates its position perfectly but I cannot figure out how to clear the last instance. Here is the line that I use to plot the 'cursor'.

```
self.cursor2 = self.p2_3.addItem(pg.ScatterPlotItem([self.xx], [self.yy], pen=None, symbol='+', color = 'b'))
```

I tried self.cursor2.clear() but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call addItem you add the plotdataitem, in this case a scatterplotitem to your plotitem. To remove it you call removeItem in the same way. But you need to keep a reference to the scatterplotitem to do that.

Note that addItem doesn't return anything i.e. your self.cursor2 is None.

If you want to remove everything from your plot you could call

```
self.p2_3.clear()
```

otherwise to just remove the scatterplotitem you can do like this

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
plotitem = win.addPlot()
scatterplot = pg.ScatterPlotItem([2], [3], symbol='+', color = 'b')

plotitem.addItem(scatterplot)
plotitem.removeItem(scatterplot)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `setData` to control `ScatterPlotItem` data instead of creating/adding/removing the object each time the mouse is moving:

```
# This just once:
self.scatterplot = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x=[], y=[], symbol='+', color = 'b')
plotitem.addItem(self.scatterplot)


# On mouse hovering:
self.scatterplot.setData(x=[self.xx], y=[self.yy])
```

It's way more efficient.